# Returning a row that has all foreign keys

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using sqlalchemy and I have a Place model and a Procedure Model. It is a many-to-many relationship between Places and Procedures, each Place has multiple procedures and a Procedure can be done by multiple places.

Currently I have a simple query so that I can search for all Places that have a single procedure.

```
for place in session.query(Place).filter(Place.procedures.any(Procedure.name == searchProcedure)):
```

This works correctly, and my query will currently return all places that have the desired search procedure.

I want to change it so that I have multiple search procedures, and I only return any places that have all of the queried search procedures.

I have a working solution using for loops to run multiple filters

```
    placeResults = session.query(Place)
    for searchProcedure in proceduresQuery:
        placeResults = placeResults.filter(Place.procedures.any(Procedure.name == searchProcedure))

    for place in placeResults:
        #do desired work with found places here
```

Is there a better way to do this with sqlalchemy (or sql in general)? I believe there is probably a shorter/faster solution involving joins, but I am not sure.

Thanks!

Comment: Edit question to show sample data and desired result as text tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the very least, if the number of procedures is relatively small, you could just `and_` the requirements together in your `.filter`:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

engine = sa.create_engine("sqlite:///:memory:", echo=True)

Base = declarative_base()

# association table
place_procedure = sa.Table(
    "place_procedure",
    Base.metadata,
    sa.Column("place_id", sa.ForeignKey("place.id"), primary_key=True),
    sa.Column("procedure_id", sa.ForeignKey("procedure.id"), primary_key=True),
)


class Place(Base):
    __tablename__ = "place"

    id = sa.Column("id", sa.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False)
    procedures = sa.orm.relationship(
        "Procedure", secondary=place_procedure, back_populates="places"
    )

    def __init__(self, id, procedures):
        self.id = id
        self.procedures = procedures

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<Place(id={self.id})>"


class Procedure(Base):
    __tablename__ = "procedure"

    id = sa.Column("id", sa.String(50), primary_key=True)
    places = sa.orm.relationship(
        "Place", secondary=place_procedure, back_populates="procedures"
    )

    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<Procedure(id='{self.id}')>"


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

Session = sa.orm.sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

# test data
proc1 = Procedure("procedure1")
proc2 = Procedure("procedure2")
proc4 = Procedure("procedure4")
place0 = Place(0, [])
place1 = Place(1, [proc1])
place2 = Place(2, [proc2])
place3 = Place(3, [proc2, proc1])
place4 = Place(4, [proc4])
place5 = Place(5, [proc4, proc1])
place6 = Place(6, [proc4, proc2])
place7 = Place(7, [proc4, proc2, proc1])
session.add_all(
    [
        proc1,
        proc2,
        proc4,
        place1,
        place2,
        place3,
        place4,
        place5,
        place6,
        place7,
    ]
)
session.commit

# test code
places_with_procedure1_and_procedure2 = (
    session.query(Place)
    .filter(
        sa.and_(
            Place.procedures.contains(proc1), Place.procedures.contains(proc2)
        )
    )
    .all()
)

print(places_with_procedure1_and_procedure2)
"""console output:
[<Place(id=3)>, <Place(id=7)>]
"""
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help! That is good enough for me for now!